# Javascript How do I add a delay on displaying the DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to add a delay in displaying a page in my app. I am using angularjs framework. The reason why i need to do this is because, even though my DOM is fully rendered, the data from angularjs is still being read and not added to the DOM. I have tried adding timeout to the **ui-view** BUT it doesnt do the trick.

Comment: Doesn't whatever reads the data have some sort of complete callback?

Comment: For additional info, i am reading a json object from a pretty big json file. Whats happening is i have a directive that binds an element value to the json object.  Even though the html element is already loaded e.g span, and the value inside the span is still being fetch from the json file which is causing a delay on displaying the value inside the span element.

Comment: The best approach would be to add a resolve to the router, so the view doesn't even load until after your JSON is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use timeout function :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.myHeader = "Hello World!";
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.myHeader = "How are you today?";
    }, 2000);
});
```

[More Information ...](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get why you want to delay page loading

What I understood from your problem is that your page is getting displayed in uncompiled form
try to use

```
ng-cloack directive
```

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

The directive can be applied to the `<body>` element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view.

here is complete documentation

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 0):

Use the resolve option to load your JSON before the view is loaded. [Documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

For example:

```
resolve: {
    return $http({method: 'GET', url: '/someUrl'})
               .then (function (data) {
                   return doSomeStuffFirst(data);
               });
}
```